# Access puts HTML div in linked SharePoint tabel

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint

I have a table in Access that is linked to SharePoint called Actions. In SharePoint the field Remarks is defined as Single line of text, not required, not unique, with a length of 255 characters. In Access I see this field with the same specs. In the form to fill the field I cannot find any attribute that would cause my problem. 
When I write a single line of text in the input form like

```
    Add new Machine
```

it is saved in SharePoint as

```
    <div>Add new Machine</div>
```

How and why does this happen?
Hope someone knows the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Update! It looks like it has nothing to do with SharePoint. I removed the linked tables. Then build new, local tabels, but used the same queries and forms, and still the < div>'s are added. So it seems to be a problem in the form or the formfield attribute, or in the definition of the field in the table. Suggestions anyone? Tnx

Comment: Solution: rebuilt every form where this problem occurs.... Only updating the fields in the existing form did not work. Now I've created new forms and it no longer shows or saves the HTML tags. Very strange. Anyway, happy with the result. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that Access sees this field as "Rich Text" for some reason.

I would check the "[Text Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192700.aspx)" property of the Remarks field in the entry form you are referring to. In design view on the form, select the textbox and open up the Properties menu for the textbox. The "Data" tab is where the "Text Format" property should be located. If it is set to "[Rich Text](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834435.aspx)", change it to "Plain Text".

If, however, the textbox needs to be rich text, I would recommend changing the data type of the field in SharePoint to "Multi Lines of Text" and make sure that field can hold rich text content. Then, if needed, use logic in Access to limit entry to 255 characters.

Comment: The field in Access is already Plain text. I do not need Rich text. :(

Comment: Even more, if I try to change the input field to rich text on the form (just checking) I get an error message "The setting you entered isnt valid for this property". ??

Comment: I'm at a lost then why this is happening. What happens when you try to enter information into the field on SharePoint? Does it still put the rich text "<div>" around the entry? Also, what version of SharePoint are you using?

Comment: I'm using SharePoint 2013, Access Professional Plus 2010. When working directly in SharePoint the problem does not occur.

Comment: I found a work around by using PlainText(me.Remarks). However, as it happens in more than 1 field this is not a very nice solution.